# i am getting this error failed to execute request because the app-domain could not be created on IIS 5.1 win XP

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, iis-5

i am getting this error "failed to execute request because the app-domain could not be created" on IIS 5.1 win XP

any ideas? i tried looking online....i put my .net application in the INETPUB folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three ideas, all fairly basic.
1. Make sure you have the proper .NET frameworks installed.
2. Make sure you have your virtual directory set to the right framework.
3. Run this in the command line to make sure your IIS/.NET permissions are correct.

> c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe
>   -i

Answer (score 2):

Run the `iisreset` command from an elevated command prompt.